# $( this ).attr('value') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to get the value or id of a `li` element on clicking. Everything I've tried returns `undefined`

HTML

```
<ul id="list" class="content-ul">
    <li value="0"><img src="/image0.png" /></li>
    <li value="1"><img src="/image1.png" /></li>
    <li value="2"><img src="/image2.png" /></li>
    <li value="3"><img src="/image3.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$( '#list li' ).click( ( event ) => {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(value); // returns undefined
} );
```

I've tried using `this.id` as well as `$( this ).id` - undefined

I've tried giving the `img` tag an `id` and a `value` - still undefined

I've tried giving the `li` tag an `id` - still again, undefined

Comment: don't use an arrow function if you want `this` to be the target element - i.e. use `function ( event ) {`

Comment: @VardanBetikyan  read here why: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/when-you-should-not-use-arrow-functions/. And kindly close the question

Comment: The reason why the code returns undefined is because `this` inside the arrow function does not refer to the DOM element that was clicked.

Comment: I always assumed an arrow function is just a shorthand method. Guess not, thanks guys!

Comment: try using `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this** inside the arrow function does not refer to the DOM element that was clicked.

```js
$( '#list li' ).click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(value); // returns undefined
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list" class="content-ul">
    <li value="0"><img src="/image0.png" /></li>
    <li value="1"><img src="/image1.png" /></li>
    <li value="2"><img src="/image2.png" /></li>
    <li value="3"><img src="/image3.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `this` context cannot be bound manually by jQuery with an arrow function. Use a regular `function` or use `event.currentTarget` to access the element the event listener is attached to.

```js
$('#list li').click( ( event ) => {
    var value = $(event.currentTarget).attr('value');
    console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list" class="content-ul">
    <li value="0"><img src="/image0.png" /></li>
    <li value="1"><img src="/image1.png" /></li>
    <li value="2"><img src="/image2.png" /></li>
    <li value="3"><img src="/image3.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add the other solution as suggested in the comments as well so that OP can get both ideas. though a good answer +1

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie I did mention using a regular function and the code for that has already been covered by other answers, so I don't feel it's necessary to repeat it.

Comment: Unmitigated yes, totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put an "a" tag with a class and put an image inside?

Put the atrribut on the "a" tag like below:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="something" data-id="01"><img src="">
<a href="#" class="something" data-id="12"><img src="">
```

jQuery

```
$('.something').on('click', function () {
    id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(id);
    alert("the Id is : " + id);
});
```

You can make your own data atribute, like data-id, data-name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This context cannot be bound manually by jQuery with the arrow function. Use a regular function or use event.currentTarget to access the element attached to the event listener.

```js
    $('#list li').click( ( event ) => {
        var value = $(event.currentTarget).attr('value');
        // console.log(value);
        alert(value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="list" class="content-ul">
        <li value="0">image code0</li>
        <li value="1">image code1</li>
        <li value="3">image code3</li>
    </ul>
```